# spring-cloud https with spring cloud gateway 2.0

Tags: spring-cloud

Trying out the spring cloud gateway 2.0.
A simple path rewrite route works well. But switching to https, the route starts failing.

Code to reproduce the issue can be found at https://github.com/saiyedzaidi/spring-cloud-gateway-https
URI /test is a simple controller, always works irrespective of https
URI /try/1 is a proxy, only works without https.

Is there anything I am doing wrong here ? or perhaps point out which classes I should start looking into to fix it, if it's a bug.

Comment: Can you provide an error message or how it fails?

Comment: hitting https://localhost:8080/try/1 causes  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get SSL certificates
 at DefaultSslInfo.initCertificates(DefaultSslInfo.java:94)
 at DefaultSslInfo.<init>(DefaultSslInfo.java:51)
 at ReactorServerHttpRequest.initSslInfo(ReactorServerHttpRequest.java:141)
 at AbstractServerHttpRequest.getSslInfo(AbstractServerHttpRequest.java:162)
 <Trace - truncated>
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
while https://localhost:8080/test continues to work

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/159